# How does one actually use kabbalistic kavanot during prayer?

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, kavana-concentration

My question is concerning the issue of the kabbalistic kavanot and yichudim which are present in the various Kabbalistic siddurim available on the market.

There are numerous such siddurim available today. I have a particular interest in the siddur of Rabbi Shabtai of Rashkov and Rabbi Asher Margaliot (both of whom were well acquainted with the Besht, the Baal Shem Tov-the founder of the Chassidic movement) mostly because I am very fond of Chassidus in general. I also have an interest in the siddur and kavanot of Rabbi Shalom Sharabi.

These siddurim are pretty much like any other siddur, with the exception that they contain many elaborate and often-times complicated kavanot and special meditations for the different parts of the prayer service. I am already familiar with some kabbalistic concepts and terminology (such as the sefirot/partzufim, gilgul, the four worlds, gematria, etc.) but my primary interest is in how one is actually supposed to incorporate these concepts in the kavanot and yichudim while praying.

For example, in the first verse of the Shema, each one of the words has a particular correspondence to one of the sefirot or partzufim (such as Chokhma or Zeir Anpin). While saying the Shema, are we supposed to just keep these Sefirot in mind as we say each of the words or is there something else we are supposed to do while saying each of the words?

There are also many other kavanot and meditations for the rituals and activities that we do throughout the day, such as for washing the hands, putting on the tallit and tefillin, making kiddush, immersing in the mikvah, even eating and drinking!

How does one actually use these kavanot in the prayers, practically speaking? Does anyone here actually use any of these siddurim on a day-to-day basis?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: All of the siddurim you mentioned are based on the work of the Rashash. Without going too far into detail, some of these kaavanot are used exactly the way you propose for the Shema. Others are used in completely different ways

Comment: It is not proper to go into too much detail on this topic on the open internet, and who says I'm even an expert?

Comment: I think the best way would be to have a teacher that can show you. Not so easy to find though. Best of success.